# Why do i see double rows in Hyperledger Explorer after running it

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, explorer, hyperledger-explorer

I have configured my Fabric network and attached Hyperledger Explorer to it. After i run the explorer tool i am facing an weird issue where i see double entry of rows in the following 3 sections. Initally i though it might be an caching issue so i removed cache from the browser, but to no avail. The issue persists.

It would be very helpful if anyone can tell me if they faced something similar or point out where i might be going wrong or any suggestions. I am really stuck with this one.

Double Rows as seen on **Dashboard Tab** - You can see that the peers and orderers are being shown twice

[image]

Double Rows as seen on **Network Tab** - You can see that the peers and orderers are being shown twice

[image]

Double Rows being shown on the **Chaincodes Tab**

[image]

Hyperledger Explorer - Version: 1.1.1 (July 17,2020)
Hyperledger Fabric - Version:1.4.6

Comment: you can ask it in the official fabrci-explorer group
https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/hyperledger-explorer

Comment: Ahh...they have closed new user registrations for now.

Comment: No it's not closed. first you have to create an account on linux foundation then use those credentials to sign-in to hyperledger chat